# SAS with units sum

Tags: sas

I want to sum units by mbr and date of service level and also want to add a column where the column would show the total of each previous units, for example

```
Mbr*id      DOS       units     Total_sum*\_units    
AA        1/1/2023    10            10   
AA        1/2/2023    10             20    
AA       1/3/2023     50             70    
AA       1/4/2023     50            120    
BB        1/1/2023    15            15    
BB        1/2/2023    10             25    
BB       1/3/2023     30             55    
BB       1/4/2023     45            100
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to use proc sql for the above issue and using the tool called SAS for the above scenario.

I want to sum units by mbr and date of service level and also want to add a colum where the colum would show the total of each previous units, for example

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to use PROC SQL for the above issue and using the tool called SAS for the above scenario.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to use proc sql for the above issue and using the tool called SAS for the above scenario.

I want to sum units by mbr and date of service level and also want to add a colum where the colum would show the total of each previous units, for example

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to use PROC SQL for the above issue and using the tool called SAS for the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a running sum (or cumulative total).  That is not something you can do easily in SQL since SQL does not know anything about order.  So the best way is to calculate the the value in normal SAS code since that will process the data in the order provided.

So first let's convert your listing into an actual dataset.

```
data have ;
  input mbr $ dos :mmddyy. units expect;
  format dos yymmdd10.;
cards;
AA 1/1/2023 10  10
AA 1/2/2023 10  20
AA 1/3/2023 50  70
AA 1/4/2023 50 120
BB 1/1/2023 15  15
BB 1/2/2023 10  25
BB 1/3/2023 30  55
BB 1/4/2023 45 100
;
```

Now assuming the data is already sorted a simple data step using a SUM statement will generate the new variable.  Just make sure to reset the value when starting a new MBR.

```
data want;
   set have ;
   by mbr dos ;
   total + units;
   if first.mbr then total=units;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    mbr           dos    units    expect    total

 1     AA     2023-01-01      10        10       10
 2     AA     2023-01-02      10        20       20
 3     AA     2023-01-03      50        70       70
 4     AA     2023-01-04      50       120      120
 5     BB     2023-01-01      15        15       15
 6     BB     2023-01-02      10        25       25
 7     BB     2023-01-03      30        55       55
 8     BB     2023-01-04      45       100      100
```

To do it with SQL you will need use a self-join of the data with itself. Which for large dataset could be a lot of work.

```
proc sql;
create table want2 as
  select a.mbr,a.dos,a.units,a.expect,sum(b.units) as total
  from have a 
  inner join have b 
    on a.mbr=b.mbr and b.dos <= a.dos
  group by a.mbr,a.dos,a.units,a.expect
  order by a.mbr,a.dos
;
quit;
```

**PS** Displaying dates in MDY or DMY order will confuse half of your audience.  Your example data could just as easily been intended as monthly data instead of daily data if one used the DDMMYY informat to read it instead of the MMDDYY informat I used.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I checked the sas code and it works fine